# ImageMagick: Watermark image and keep file name

Tags: imagemagick, watermark

I have this code but I would like to edit it so the exported file name is the same as the file name used to make it

```
mogrify -composite -gravity center ~/Desktop/civmap-client-master/data/watermark.png ~/Desktop/civmap-client-master/data/nowm/*.png ~/Desktop/civmap-client-master/data/wm/*.png
```

It just throws an error when I used *.png as my exported file name. Please note I have multiple files in the /nowm/ directory. I am using a Mac.

Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mogrify` command does not accept `-composite` as an operation as it takes just 2 images. You will have to use a loop:

```
cd ~/Desktop/where/the/input/images/are
for f in *.png; do 
  echo $f
  convert -gravity center "$f" "~/Desktop/path/to/watermark.png" -composite "~/Desktop/path/to/output/$f"
done
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn, well spotted!