# watermarking during image downsize

Tags: imagemagick, watermark

I am using *mogrify* utility to batch converting images and preparing them for web.
Bumped with a question how to do watermark using same *mogrify* utility. There are a lot of examples with how to watermark but all of them using *composite* utility. It is not suitable for me as I dont want to split process into two steps.

Here is a simplified command line

```
mogrify -resize 400x400 -tile WATERMARK_FILE.png -path out\ input.jpg
```

it is do resize but does not compose with watermark

**UPDATE:**
Unfortunately its inpossible to do it by single step (via morgify). Although morgify accepts the -tile parameter it result to nothing. Probably its is a bug, because image to tile is read from disk but not used.

I solved the task by separately preparing watermark tiled image by size equalent or bigger then destination images.

```
:: prepare emty transparent image  with size %IMG_SIZE%
convert -size %IMG_SIZE% xc:none "%WATERMARK_BASE_FILE%"
:: tile watermark on it
composite -dissolve 30 -tile "%WATERMARK_FILE%" "%WATERMARK_BASE_FILE%" "%WATERMARK_TILED_FILE%"
:: resize images and draw watermark on each image
morgify -resize %IMG_SIZE% -gravity center -draw "image src-over 0,0 0,0 '%WATERMARK_FILE%'" -path "%DST_DIR%" "%SRC_MASK%"
```

Comment: Please have a look here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/31898910/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell, its not an option, since I do not want to use loop (its slow, slower then batch morgify). Moreover morgify itself accepts -tile command (but without profit)

Comment: @MarkSetchell, yes, currently I am on windows. But I want to find out cross-platform solution

Comment: You should look at `GNU Parallel`, try searching my other answers. Something like `parallel convert {} -resize 400x400 watermark.png -composite out/{} ::: *.jpg`

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I am trying to go away from runing 'convert' in the loop. But thanks a lot. 
It is strange that morgify is accepted -tile parameter(and water_mark file is readed), but it do nothing with it.

Comment: I had used [sharp module](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) for nodejs now, and it completely satisfy my needs. NodeJS seems like not lightweight script engine, but **damn it works 20x (sic!) times faster** than Imagemagick.
Completely disappointed with Imagemagick and dropped using it